# Having problems getting nginx running

Tags: nginx

I'm running nginx on EC2, with the goal of setting up phabricator. This is my nginx.conf file:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user  eng;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

This is conf.d:

```
 " ============================================================================
 " Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v134)
 "   /etc/nginx/conf.d
 "   Sorted by      name
 "   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
 "   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec   
 " ============================================================================
 ../
 virtual.conf
```

In my sites-enabled, I have a  symlink to a configuration, phabricator.mysite.com, which is located in sites-available. Here are the contents of phabricator.mysite.com:

```
 ## Phabricator
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  phabricator.mysite.com;

    root   /home/eng/phabricator/phabricator/webroot;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    location / {
        index  index.php;
        if ( !-f $request_filename )
        {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?__path__=/$1 last;
            break;
        }
    }

    location /index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;

        #required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
        fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

        #variables to make the $_SERVER populate in PHP
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

When I try to access phabricator.mysite.com, I get the following error in my nginx error log:

```
2013/08/29 04:12:52 [error] 30977#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 50.240.220.206, server: phabricator.mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "phabricator.mysite.com"
```

THe permissions for my webroot folder are set to 755.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What research have you done? From what I've seen it may be related to a wrongly set SCRIPT_FILENAME in the nginx fastcgi_param directive.

Comment: I've been Googling around for several hours. The fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; comes from the config at http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Configuration_Guide.html . It may be wrong. Where would I find the values being assigned to these variables? I know that $document_root is set in the root directive--which is correct (If I put an html file in my root folder I can access it no problem). Where can I find the value of $fastcgi_script_name?

Comment: It think you should add the relevant information in your questions, so people answering it can do a good job.

Comment: What information am I missing that I can provide? I'd be more than happy to, I'm just not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Everything you said in your comment. I'm just pointing out that this information is valuable and probably worth throwing in the question in the fist place.

Comment: @Catherine `$fastcgi_script_name` is explained in the [FastCGI module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#variables).

Comment: @Changaco Thanks. I had come across that, so I'm fairly sure that wasn't the issue. I ended up going with a socket rather than a port and that seemed to fix my issues, at least temporarily. Should answer the question I guess...

Answer (score 1):

This is a copy/paste from my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090350/nginx-unable-to-open-primary-script/31907528#31907528 .  I actually ran into this same issue getting Phabricator set up a Google Cloud box.

SELinux will cause this error on CentOS/RHEL 7+ by default :(

To test if SELinux is the source of your woes, do

```
setenforce 0
```

... and see if everything works. If that fixed it, you can leave SELinux off (weak, you're better than that), or you can turn it back on with

```
setenforce 1
```

... and then properly fix the issue.

If you do

```
tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

... you'll see the SELinux issue. In my case, it was denying PHP-FPM access to web files. You can run the following directives to fix it:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

This actually didn't fix it for me at first, but then restoring SELinux context did it

```
restorecon -R -v /var/www
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your problem was "Primary script unknown"?

Comment: Yup: 2015/08/09 18:14:31 [error] 10052#0: *20 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response
 header from upstream, client: 123.123.123.123, server: portal.myserver.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upst
ream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "portal.myserver.com"

Answer (score 0):

add following line after, "location /index.php {" in location section

root   /home/eng/phabricator/phabricator/webroot;

Comment: Nope, that's not it. PHP FPM is running. Calling netstat -lpn shows, among other things: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25141/php-fpm`